How to mouseover and mouse out on all buttons in JavaScript
I would like for an image of my project to show on the mouseover as it does on the first one. I'm a little confused as to how to get it to show when I hover over the rest?
Code Pen: https://codepen.io/Ismail-Shaikh-the-lessful/pen/azoZvXL
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
});

const img     = document.getElementById("images");
const project = document.getElementById("project");
const text    = document.querySelector(".text");

project.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (img.style.display === "none") {
    img.style.display  = "block";
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
});

project.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  if (img.style.display === "block") {
    img.style.display = "none";
    text.style.display = "block";
  }
});

I tried this and it worked ONLY on the first project and not the others. I expected it would work on the rest of the projects but does not.

Side note, IDs must be unique

Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

Given the comment above and the lack of HTML in the question, I'm guessing you have a number of elements with id=project - this line document.getElementById("project") is single (getElement...) not (getElements) - so will only return a single element - so only works for the first one.

The problem is you have multiple elements with the same id. The id's "project", "link", and "images" are all used on multiple elements. Unlike a class, an id needs to be unique to a single element.
Either change your id's to be classes, or change them to each be a unique id.
If you change those id's to be classes, then you can add event listeners for all your .projects, pass event into the handlers, then access the images and text off the event.target.
Example edit of your JavaScript to do that:
NOTE: See the EDIT comments for specific changes.
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
});

// EDIT Don't need this now
//const img = document.getElementById("images");

// EDIT Changed to using a class
//const project = document.getElementById("project");
const projects = document.querySelectorAll(".project");

// EDIT Don't need this now. It wasn't working correctly anyway
const text = document.querySelector(".text");

// Add a listener for each of the project buttons
for( let project of projects ) {
  // EDIT Added event parameter
  project.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    // EDIT Added
    const img = event.target.querySelector("img");
    if (img && img.style.display === "none") {
      // EDIT Added
      const text = event.target.querySelector(".text");
      img.style.display = "block";
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}

// Add a listener for each of the project buttons
for( let project of projects ) {
  // EDIT Added event parameter
  project.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    // EDIT Added
    const img = event.target.querySelector("img");
    if (img && img.style.display === "block") {
      // EDIT Added
      const text = event.target.querySelector(".text");
      img.style.display = "none";
      text.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}


"change them to each be a unique id which would likely be an anti-pattern, so don't so that - just use classes.
